# Would WebRTC use a constant frame rate to capture video frame

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, h.264

Would WebRTC use a constant frame rate to capture H264 streaming?I can only find the max frame rate configuration.

Comment: no, i think it is variable, the exact frame rate at any point can be seen using `getStats` API of webrtc.

Comment: @mido22 That's the framerate for rendering though, I don't think the capturing framerate is variable, unless you re-init your capturer.

Comment: @Kevin, my bad, took it as rendering frame rate, is the capture frame rate even under control, thought chrome just ignored that property in `getUserMedia` constraints

Comment: @mido22 Yeah it's weird, I know in iOS you can use constraints to set it, and it might work, or not..... Chrome seems to completely ignore those constraints and I'm not far enough with our android app yet to say anything about that. What I do know is that the iPhone 6 can capture at 240 fps, but the resulting stream is at a way lower framerate, so webrtc does some scaling between capturing and spitting out the video track.

Comment: I would think that the framerate is modified directly in the h264 bitstream, same with framesizes(which are modified in vp8). Or at least, down stream from the capturing point but upstream from the actual encoding.